# unable to add formatting to excel sheet using pandas and xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm able to transfer data from datafile.xlsx to test.xlsx, but I don't know how to add the color red to specific cells in test.xlsx

#The major components of the code are shown below

```
import pandas as pd 
import xlsxwriter

file = "datafile.xlsx"
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(file)
sheet1 = xlsx.parse(0)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx")
columns=["FirstName", "MiddleName", "LastName", ......]

#--My code doesn't work when a sheet_name is added in the to_excel piece--

dfc = pd.DataFrame([columns])
dfc.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheet1, startrow=0, startcol=0, 
index=False, header=None) 

#The body of the code retrieves data from datafile.xlsx
#example--> row = sheet1.iloc[i].real

#---This section has my new code for adding cell color-----
#---cell color code(I define a workbook and worksheet)
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['sheet1']
cell_format = workbook.add_format()  
cell_format.set_font_color('red')
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Foo', cell_format)
#----cell color code

dt = [row[0], row[1], row[2], .....]
df1 = pd.DataFrame([dt])
df1.to_excel(writer, startrow=rownum, startcol=0, index=False, header=None)  
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to change the color of the cell and not the color of the font then change

```
cell_format.set_font_color('red')
```

for

```
cell_format.set_bg_color('red')
```